# invoke a button click event from main activity when the button is inside another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, layout, android-button, main-activity

I am trying to write a `setOnClickListener` to a button which is inside an other `fragment` called `InsertFragment` from my main activity

I am new to android development so that I can't understand why I am getting this error. I have tried to use `setContentView(R.layout.fragment_insert)` but that didn't work

my fragment will be called when I choose the relevant fragment from the menu bar

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

This is the error I am getting. Please correct my mistakes. Thanks in advance

Comment: you can't call the your fragment views from your activity. and let us know why you are trying to access your fragment button from activity?

Comment: provide the code please

Comment: @RajasekaranM since my menu bar is inside the main activity. An also I could't use findViewByid(R.id.my_id) method inside the fragment class. That's why I tried this way

Comment: good use callback for communicate to your activity

Comment: @SauravKumar case R.id.nav_insert:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new InsertFragment()).commit();
                ExecuteInsertFrame();
                break;

Comment: It's will helpful for you https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating

Comment: @RajasekaranM Thank you for the resource you have provided. instead of using callbacks I have used intents to pass data from fragment to my main activity. But the thing is still I am getting an null exception. Can you tell me why is that

Comment: @RajasekaranM your link was very useful. Using that interface I was able to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Button is declared and Initialized

something Like

```
Button addButton = findViewById(R.id.add_button);
```

Comment: This means you are invoke the OnClickListener on a null Reference of the Button Class

Comment: I was able to fix that issue by initializing those view(Button , Edit text) inside my fragment. Then I tried to pass those data to my main activity via intents. But still I get a null exception

Comment: public void sendData()
    {

        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(),MainActivity.class);

        //PACK DATA
        i.putExtra("SENDER_KEY", "InsertFragment");
        i.putExtra("NAME_KEY", name.getText().toString());
        i.putExtra("DESCRIPTION_KEY",description.getText().toString());
        i.putExtra("PRICE_KEY", Float.valueOf(price.getText().toString()));

        //RESET WIDGETS
        name.setText("");
        description.setText("");
        price.setText("");

        //START ACTIVITY
        getActivity().startActivity(i);

    }